# Show that group has a nontrivial normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and assume that it has an irreducible (complex) character of degree $2$. How can I prove that then $G$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup?

I tried to prove that for the 2-dimensional representation $G \to \text{Aut}(V)$, we either have that the kernel is trivial or not, if its not we are done and if it is we know that the center $Z(G)=Z(\chi)$ is cyclic, maybe in this case the center is not trivial and hence we are done?

I am stuck at the moment, and I am looking for hints.

EDIT: I know that a group $G$ has a nontrivial normal subgroup if it has a conjugacy class $C$ such that $\mid C \mid = p^k$ for some prime $p$ and $k > 0$, I tried to use this aswell but didn't manage.

Comment: If $G$ has an irreducible character of degree $2$, then $|G|>1$ and so $G$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt why does it have a nontrivial normal subgroup if its order is strictly bigger than 1? That actually want I am trying to prove, your first statement is trivial.

Comment: My comment was a nitpick. What you are looking for is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup.

Answer (score 3):

If the representation has a kernel, then you're done. If $\det$ of the representation is nontrivial, then you're also done. If neither of these conditions holds, then $G$ is a finite subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. From here try to show that $G$ has nontrivial center. (As a bonus you can try to completely classify the finite subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$: the answer is quite nice.)

Comment: What is $det$? The determinant? Can you explain that sentence including det please.

Comment: @koopi: the determinant of a representation is its top exterior power. Explicitly it's given by taking the determinant of all of the matrices involved.

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate on Qiaochu Yuan's answer, you don't need the full classification of finite subgroups of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb C})$.

Since $G$ has an irreducible character of degree $2$, $|G|$ must be even, and so it has an element $t$ of order $2$. But the only element of order $2$ in ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb C})$ is $-I_2$, so $t$ must map onto $-I_2$ in the representation. Since $-I_2 \in Z({\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb C}))$, we have $t \in Z(G)$, and hence $\langle t \rangle$ is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.